# Console.log(array) prints a result, but return(array) is undefined

Tags: javascript, dom-events

When I clicked on the .user-name, I wrote the code to filter out only the inner-text of the .user-name and the value of DATA.user are the same.

Console.log(array) prints a result, but return(array) is undefined

Why is that?

```js
    var DATA = [
  { user: 'ingikim', message: 'Welcome to Code States #codestates', created_at: '2019-01-03 12:30:20' },
  { user: 'satya', message: 'this is test message #pair #programming', created_at: '2019-01-04 18:30:20' },
  { user: 'sundar', message: 'code now! #work #hard', created_at: '2019-01-05 07:30:20' },
  { user: 'steve', message: 'Stay hungry, and stay foolish', created_at: '2015-01-03 12:30:20' },
  { user: 'tim', message: 'education for real world', created_at: '2019-01-04 18:30:20' }
];
function userNameFilter() {
  const tweets = document.querySelector('.tweets');

  function userListPrint(target) {
    return DATA.filter(function(el) {
      console.log('-------------------')
      console.log('e.target.innerText : ' + target.innerText)
      console.log('el`enter code here`.user : ' + el.user)
      console.log(el.user === target.innerText)
      return el.user === target.innerText
    })
  }
  tweets.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.className === 'user-name') {
      userListPrint(e.target)
      console.log(userListPrint(e.target))
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<ul class="tweets">
  <li>
    <p class="user-info">
      <button class="user-name">신규유저</button>
      <span class="timestamp">2018-12-24 18:16:21</span>
    </p>
    <p class="user-message">texttexttexttexttext</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is DATA object?

Comment: it's seem some parts of code is missing, what is data ? when do you execute `userNameFilter`?

Comment: Hi and welcome on StackOverflow. First thing you could do is output your `DATA` object to see if it is correctly filled. Then you could put the result of `DATA.filter` in a variable and output it before it's returned.

Answer (score 0):

> Console.log(array) prints a result, but return(array) is undefined Why is that?

With the provided the DATA variable, the `filter` method on it returns an empty array `[]` and not `undefined` when searching for '신규유저'.

```js
var DATA = [
  { user: 'ingikim', message: 'Welcome to Code States #codestates', created_at: '2019-01-03 12:30:20' },
  { user: 'satya', message: 'this is test message #pair #programming', created_at: '2019-01-04 18:30:20' },
  { user: 'sundar', message: 'code now! #work #hard', created_at: '2019-01-05 07:30:20' },
  { user: 'steve', message: 'Stay hungry, and stay foolish', created_at: '2015-01-03 12:30:20' },
  { user: 'tim', message: 'education for real world', created_at: '2019-01-04 18:30:20' }
];

function userNameFilter() {
  const tweets = document.querySelector('.tweets');

  function userListPrint(target) {
    return DATA.filter(function(el) {
      console.log('-------------------')
      console.log('e.target.innerText : ' + target.innerText)
      console.log('el.user : ' + el.user)
      console.log(el.user === target.innerText)
      return el.user === target.innerText
    })
  }
  tweets.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.className === 'user-name') {
      userListPrint(e.target)
      console.log(userListPrint(e.target))
    }
  });
}
userNameFilter();
```

```html
<ul class="tweets">
  <li>
    <p class="user-info">
      <button class="user-name">신규유저</button>
      <span class="timestamp">2018-12-24 18:16:21</span>
    </p>
    <p class="user-message">texttexttexttexttext</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I updated the DATA object and now an empty array is returned. This is correct result according to the `user-name` being searched for '신규유저'.